# iOS linphone-iphone No video only audio

Tags: ios, iphone, video, h.264, linphone

I'm doing a video intercom app, app need to call with extension, the extension is a Building intercom extension, it use h264 format video. I build the linphone sdks， version is 3.8.2-28-g5d5808b. The extension program is build with others, I do not know the contents inside, but Android's app demo have video. My iOS app no video.T_T

When I call, only audio no video.

My app debug content:

```
2015-07-18 23:24:23.690 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: received [704] new bytes from [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060]:
INVITE sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.209:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK2113000003

From: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

To: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712>

Call-ID: 1144529261

CSeq: 20 INVITE

Contact: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209:5060>

Content-Type: application/sdp

Max-Forwards: 70

User-Agent: eXosip/3.3.0

Supported: 100rel

Content-Length:   299



v=0

o=qst 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.31.209

s=conversation

c=IN IP4 192.168.31.209

t=0 0

m=audio 8018 RTP/AVP 0 8 101

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-11

m=video 8020 RTP/AVP 102

a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000

a=fmtp:102 profile-level-id=428014

2015-07-18 23:24:23.705 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000] [405] bytes parsed
2015-07-18 23:24:23.708 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000] read [299] bytes of body from [192.168.31.209:5060]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.716 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Changing [server] [INVITE] transaction [0x170147d20], from state [INIT] to [PROCEEDING]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.721 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: message sent to [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060], size: [215] bytes
SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.209:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK2113000003

From: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

To: sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712

Call-ID: 1144529261

CSeq: 20 INVITE



2015-07-18 23:24:23.727 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] New server dialog [0x1741a8ea0] , local tag [], remote tag [859743850]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.732 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] op [0x102025fc0] : set_or_update_dialog() current=[0x0] new=[0x1741a8ea0]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.735 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] new incoming call from [sip:0101101@192.168.31.209] to [sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.742 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Found payload PCMU/8000 fmtp=
2015-07-18 23:24:23.746 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Found payload PCMA/8000 fmtp=
2015-07-18 23:24:23.749 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Found payload telephone-event/8000 fmtp=0-11
2015-07-18 23:24:23.754 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Found payload H264/90000 fmtp=profile-level-id=428014
2015-07-18 23:24:23.760 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Searching for already_a_call_with_remote_address.
2015-07-18 23:24:23.765 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] New LinphoneCall [0x101804600] initialized (LinphoneCore version: 3.8.2-28-g5d5808b)
2015-07-18 23:24:23.773 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] RtpSession bound to [0.0.0.0] ports [7076] [7077]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.776 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Setting DSCP to 46 for MSAudio stream.
2015-07-18 23:24:23.780 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Equalizer location: mic
2015-07-18 23:24:23.783 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] cannot set noise gate mode to [0] because no volume send
2015-07-18 23:24:23.787 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] RtpSession bound to [0.0.0.0] ports [9078] [9079]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.793 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Setting DSCP to 0 for MSVideo stream.
2015-07-18 23:24:23.799 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Don't put video stream on local offer for call [0x101804600]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.805 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Doing SDP offer/answer process of type incoming
2015-07-18 23:24:23.810 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Declining mline 1, no corresponding stream in local capabilities description.
2015-07-18 23:24:23.815 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [show]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.818 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [display_status]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.821 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_unlink: MSFilePlayer:0x170126cc0,0-->MSDtmfGen:0x170127120,0
2015-07-18 23:24:23.825 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_unlink: MSDtmfGen:0x170127120,0-->MSResample:0x170127620,0
2015-07-18 23:24:23.830 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_unlink: MSResample:0x170127620,0-->MSAQWrite:0x1701273a0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:23.844 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136273] Ring MSTicker thread exiting
2015-07-18 23:24:23.849 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Starting local ring...
2015-07-18 23:24:23.856 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Configuring resampler input with rate=[44100], nchannels=[1]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.859 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSFilePlayer[0x170127620]: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/0C957F7E-18F8-4078-8AC9-3F7E1AB44EC4/LinphoneDemo2.app/ring.wav opened: rate=44100,channel=1
2015-07-18 23:24:23.863 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] configuring resampler output to rate=[44100], nchannels=[1]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.867 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSFilePlayer:0x170127620,0-->MSDtmfGen:0x1701273a0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:23.867 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136424] Priority used: 47
2015-07-18 23:24:23.871 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSDtmfGen:0x1701273a0,0-->MSResample:0x170126cc0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:23.876 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136424] Ring MSTicker priority set to SCHED_RR and value (47)
2015-07-18 23:24:23.881 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSResample:0x170126cc0,0-->MSAQWrite:0x170127120,0
2015-07-18 23:24:23.891 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Initializing speex resampler in mode [voip]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.895 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] AQ: Configuring audio session for playback
2015-07-18 23:24:23.901 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Call 0x101804600: moving from state LinphoneCallIdle to LinphoneCallIncomingReceived
2015-07-18 23:24:23.904 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_state_changed]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.912 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Incoming call
2015-07-18 23:24:23.921 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Contact has been fixed using proxy
2015-07-18 23:24:23.926 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: message sent to [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060], size: [292] bytes
SIP/2.0 180 Ringing

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.209:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK2113000003

From: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

To: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712>;tag=0zmDcr2

Call-ID: 1144529261

CSeq: 20 INVITE

User-Agent: /mikko1.0 (belle-sip/1.4.1)

Supported: outbound



2015-07-18 23:24:23.932 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Dialog [0x1741a8ea0]: now updated by transaction [0x170147d20].
2015-07-18 23:24:23.938 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: ending recv background task with id=[4].
2015-07-18 23:24:23.976 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: starting recv background task with id=[6].
2015-07-18 23:24:23.979 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: received [704] new bytes from [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060]:
INVITE sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.209:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK2113000003

From: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

To: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712>

Call-ID: 1144529261

CSeq: 20 INVITE

Contact: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209:5060>

Content-Type: application/sdp

Max-Forwards: 70

User-Agent: eXosip/3.3.0

Supported: 100rel

Content-Length:   299



v=0

o=qst 0 0 IN IP4 192.168.31.209

s=conversation

c=IN IP4 192.168.31.209

t=0 0

m=audio 8018 RTP/AVP 0 8 101

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:101 0-11

m=video 8020 RTP/AVP 102

a=rtpmap:102 H264/90000

a=fmtp:102 profile-level-id=428014

2015-07-18 23:24:23.984 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000] [405] bytes parsed
2015-07-18 23:24:23.987 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000] read [299] bytes of body from [192.168.31.209:5060]
2015-07-18 23:24:23.990 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Found transaction [0x170147d20] matching request.
2015-07-18 23:24:23.995 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: message sent to [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060], size: [292] bytes
SIP/2.0 180 Ringing

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.209:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK2113000003

From: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

To: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712>;tag=0zmDcr2

Call-ID: 1144529261

CSeq: 20 INVITE

User-Agent: /mikko1.0 (belle-sip/1.4.1)

Supported: outbound



2015-07-18 23:24:24.000 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: ending recv background task with id=[6].
2015-07-18 23:24:24.025 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] incoming call ringing for 1 seconds
2015-07-18 23:24:24.087 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136424] Ring MSTicker: We are late of 122 miliseconds.
2015-07-18 23:24:25.005 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] incoming call ringing for 2 seconds
2015-07-18 23:24:25.836 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] stop ringing
2015-07-18 23:24:25.860 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_unlink: MSFilePlayer:0x170127620,0-->MSDtmfGen:0x1701273a0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:25.866 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_unlink: MSDtmfGen:0x1701273a0,0-->MSResample:0x170126cc0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:25.871 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_unlink: MSResample:0x170126cc0,0-->MSAQWrite:0x170127120,0
2015-07-18 23:24:25.886 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136424] Ring MSTicker thread exiting
2015-07-18 23:24:25.893 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Don't put video stream on local offer for call [0x101804600]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.896 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] configuring prefered card sampling rate to [48000]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.899 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Accepting server transaction [0x170147d20] on op [0x102025fc0]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.902 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Doing SDP offer/answer process of type incoming
2015-07-18 23:24:25.906 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Declining mline 1, no corresponding stream in local capabilities description.
2015-07-18 23:24:25.912 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: message sent to [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060], size: [730] bytes
SIP/2.0 200 Ok

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.209:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK2113000003

From: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

To: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712>;tag=0zmDcr2

Call-ID: 1144529261

CSeq: 20 INVITE

User-Agent: /mikko1.0 (belle-sip/1.4.1)

Supported: outbound

Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, INFO, UPDATE

Contact: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712>;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:7d033137-3e3f-461b-850c-402676c76e28>"

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length: 193



v=0

o=test2 622 2564 IN IP4 192.168.31.232

s=Talk

c=IN IP4 192.168.31.232

b=AS:380

t=0 0

m=audio 7076 RTP/AVP 0 8 101

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

m=video 0 RTP/AVP 0

a=inactive

2015-07-18 23:24:25.918 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Changing [server] [INVITE] transaction [0x170147d20], from state [PROCEEDING] to [ACCEPTED]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.923 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Dialog [0x1741a8ea0]: now updated by transaction [0x170147d20].
2015-07-18 23:24:25.928 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [display_status]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.931 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Call 0x101804600: moving from state LinphoneCallIncomingReceived to LinphoneCallConnected
2015-07-18 23:24:25.935 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_state_changed]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.943 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] er/LinphoneManager.m:2193 - Adding CT call center listener [0x170436020]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.948 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Connected
2015-07-18 23:24:25.952 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] linphone_call_start_media_streams() call=[0x101804600] local upload_bandwidth=[380] kbit/s; local download_bandwidth=[380] kbit/s
2015-07-18 23:24:25.957 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Audio bandwidth for this call is 80
2015-07-18 23:24:25.962 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] RtpSession [0x1010e1e00] sending to rtp [192.168.31.209:8018] rtcp [192.168.31.209:8019] 
2015-07-18 23:24:25.969 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Stun packet sent for session [0x1010e1e00]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.975 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] target bitrate not set for stream [0x100f64fb0] using payload's bitrate is 80000
2015-07-18 23:24:25.978 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Setting audio encoder network bitrate to [80000] on stream [0x100f64fb0]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.983 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Equalizer rate: 8000, selecting 128 steps for FFT
2015-07-18 23:24:25.986 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Equalizer rate: 8000, selecting 128 steps for FFT
2015-07-18 23:24:25.989 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] configuring MSAURead-->MSUlawEnc from rate [48000] to rate [8000] and from channel [1] to channel [1]
2015-07-18 23:24:25.994 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] configuring MSUlawDec-->MSAUWrite from rate [8000] to rate [48000] and from channel [1] to channel [1]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.000 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSAURead:0x170127120,0-->MSResample:0x170128f20,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.000 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] Priority used: 47
2015-07-18 23:24:26.005 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSResample:0x170128f20,0-->MSEqualizer:0x174121cc0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.010 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] MSAudio MSTicker priority set to SCHED_RR and value (47)
2015-07-18 23:24:26.013 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSEqualizer:0x174121cc0,0-->MSVolume:0x170127c60,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.019 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSVolume:0x170127c60,0-->MSAudioMixer:0x170128c00,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.022 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSAudioMixer:0x170128c00,0-->MSUlawEnc:0x170127620,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.027 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSUlawEnc:0x170127620,0-->MSRtpSend:0x170128b60,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.033 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSRtpRecv:0x170127d00,0-->MSUlawDec:0x170128d40,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.038 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSUlawDec:0x170128d40,0-->MSGenericPLC:0x174121e00,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.043 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSGenericPLC:0x174121e00,0-->MSDtmfGen:0x170126cc0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.046 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSDtmfGen:0x170126cc0,0-->MSVolume:0x170128840,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.049 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSVolume:0x170128840,0-->MSAudioMixer:0x174123200,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.052 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSFilePlayer:0x170128020,0-->MSResample:0x170128660,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.055 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSResample:0x170128660,0-->MSAudioMixer:0x174123200,1
2015-07-18 23:24:26.060 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSAudioMixer:0x174123200,0-->MSResample:0x1701279e0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.065 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] ms_filter_link: MSResample:0x1701279e0,0-->MSAUWrite:0x1701273a0,0
2015-07-18 23:24:26.079 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Configuring audio session for playback/record
2015-07-18 23:24:26.263 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] AudioUnit created with type kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.268 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Initializing speex resampler in mode [voip] 
2015-07-18 23:24:26.270 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Initializing speex resampler in mode [voip] 
2015-07-18 23:24:26.273 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Initializing speex resampler in mode [voip] 
2015-07-18 23:24:26.275 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Audio session already correctly configured.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.282 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Not applying kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareSampleRate because asked rate is too high [44100]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.287 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSVolume set gain to [0.000000 db], [1.000000] linear
2015-07-18 23:24:26.292 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] No valid video stream defined.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.296 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] LinphoneCall[0x101804600] : payload type 0 PCMU/8000 fmtp=(null) added to frozen list.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.298 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] LinphoneCall[0x101804600] : payload type 8 PCMA/8000 fmtp=(null) added to frozen list.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.300 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] LinphoneCall[0x101804600] : payload type 101 telephone-event/8000 fmtp=(null) added to frozen list.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.302 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Call 0x101804600: moving from state LinphoneCallConnected to LinphoneCallStreamsRunning
2015-07-18 23:24:26.305 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_state_changed]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.309 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Connected (streams running)
2015-07-18 23:24:26.310 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] call answered.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.316 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: starting recv background task with id=[7].
2015-07-18 23:24:26.320 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: received [357] new bytes from [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060]:
ACK sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.209:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bK1985211473

From: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

To: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712>;tag=0zmDcr2

Call-ID: 1144529261

CSeq: 20 ACK

Contact: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209:5060>

Max-Forwards: 70

User-Agent: eXosip/3.3.0

Content-Length: 0



2015-07-18 23:24:26.325 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000] [357] bytes parsed
2015-07-18 23:24:26.328 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Incoming INVITE has ACK, dialog is happy
2015-07-18 23:24:26.332 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: ending recv background task with id=[7].
2015-07-18 23:24:26.334 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.337 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Bandwidth usage for call [0x101804600]:
RTP  audio=[d=  0.0,u=  0.0], video=[d=  0.0,u=  0.0] kbits/sec
RTCP audio=[d=  0.0,u=  0.0], video=[d=  0.0,u=  0.0] kbits/sec
2015-07-18 23:24:26.341 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Thread processing load: audio=0.003564 video=0.000000
2015-07-18 23:24:26.466 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] io unit initialized
2015-07-18 23:24:26.466 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] er/LinphoneManager.m:1775 - Current audio route is [ReceiverAndMicrophone]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.480 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] I/O unit latency [0.000000], quality [64]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.659 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Call 0x101804600: moving from state LinphoneCallStreamsRunning to LinphoneCallUpdating
2015-07-18 23:24:26.664 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_state_changed]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.668 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Updating call
2015-07-18 23:24:26.669 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [display_status]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.676 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Dialog [0x1741a8ea0]: now updated by transaction [0x17416ba00].
2015-07-18 23:24:26.679 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Changing [client] [INVITE] transaction [0x17416ba00], from state [INIT] to [CALLING]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.682 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: message sent to [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060], size: [1268] bytes
INVITE sip:0101101@192.168.31.209:5060 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.232:61712;branch=z9hG4bK.WpPTWfgST;rport

From: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232>;tag=0zmDcr2

To: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

CSeq: 111 INVITE

Call-ID: 1144529261

Max-Forwards: 70

Subject: Media change

Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, INFO, UPDATE

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length: 683

Contact: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232:61712>;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:7d033137-3e3f-461b-850c-402676c76e28>"

User-Agent: /mikko1.0 (belle-sip/1.4.1)



v=0

o=test2 622 2565 IN IP4 192.168.31.232

s=Talk

c=IN IP4 192.168.31.232

b=AS:380

t=0 0

a=rtcp-xr:rcvr-rtt=all:10000 stat-summary=loss,dup,jitt,TTL voip-metrics

m=audio 7076 RTP/AVP 96 97 98 99 0 8 101 100 102

a=rtpmap:96 opus/48000/2

a=fmtp:96 useinbandfec=1; stereo=0; sprop-stereo=0

a=rtpmap:97 SILK/16000

a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

a=fmtp:98 vbr=on

a=rtpmap:99 speex/8000

a=fmtp:99 vbr=on

a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/48000

a=rtpmap:100 telephone-event/16000

a=rtpmap:102 telephone-event/8000

m=video 9078 RTP/AVP 96 97 98

a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000

a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000

a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42801F

a=rtpmap:98 MP4V-ES/90000

a=fmtp:98 profile-level-id=3

2015-07-18 23:24:26.749 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] AudioUnit started, current hw output latency [0.000748] input [0.000204] iobuf[0.011610] hw sample rate [44100.000000]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.750 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] er/LinphoneManager.m:1775 - Current audio route is [SpeakerAndMicrophone]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.763 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] Stun packet sent for session [0x1010e1e00]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.768 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: starting recv background task with id=[8].
2015-07-18 23:24:26.770 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] MSAudio MSTicker: We are late of 473 miliseconds.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.772 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: received [276] new bytes from [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060]:
SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.232:61712;branch=z9hG4bK.WpPTWfgST;rport=61712

From: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232>;tag=0zmDcr2

To: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

Call-ID: 1144529261

CSeq: 111 INVITE

User-Agent: eXosip/3.3.0

Content-Length: 0



2015-07-18 23:24:26.774 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] MSAudioMixer [0x170128c00] is entering bypass mode.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.780 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000] [276] bytes parsed
2015-07-18 23:24:26.782 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] MSAudio MSTicker: We are late of 476 miliseconds.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.786 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Found transaction matching response.
2015-07-18 23:24:26.794 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Changing [client] [INVITE] transaction [0x17416ba00], from state [CALLING] to [PROCEEDING]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.797 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Dialog [0x1741a8ea0]: now updated by transaction [0x17416ba00].
2015-07-18 23:24:26.799 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] op [0x102025fc0] : set_or_update_dialog() current=[0x1741a8ea0] new=[0x1741a8ea0]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.802 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Op [0x102025fc0] receiving call response [100], dialog is [0x1741a8ea0] in state [BELLE_SIP_DIALOG_CONFIRMED]
2015-07-18 23:24:26.806 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: ending recv background task with id=[8].
2015-07-18 23:24:26.812 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] er/LinphoneManager.m:1775 - Current audio route is [SpeakerAndMicrophone]
2015-07-18 23:24:27.288 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] MSAudioMixer [0x174123200] is entering bypass mode.
2015-07-18 23:24:27.638 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] Sending RTCP SR compound message on session [0x1010e1e00].
2015-07-18 23:24:27.645 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio_stream_iterate[0x100f64fb0], local statistics available:
Local current jitter buffer size: 165.7ms
2015-07-18 23:24:27.648 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:29.797 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] er/LinphoneManager.m:1775 - Current audio route is [ReceiverAndMicrophone]
2015-07-18 23:24:30.368 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] Sending RTCP SR compound message on session [0x1010e1e00].
2015-07-18 23:24:30.385 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio_stream_iterate[0x100f64fb0], local statistics available:
Local current jitter buffer size:  44.2ms
2015-07-18 23:24:30.391 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:30.585 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio stream [0x100f64fb0]: receiving RTCP SR
2015-07-18 23:24:30.589 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:32.928 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] Sending RTCP SR compound message on session [0x1010e1e00].
2015-07-18 23:24:32.945 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio_stream_iterate[0x100f64fb0], local statistics available:
Local current jitter buffer size:  82.8ms
2015-07-18 23:24:32.950 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:35.205 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio stream [0x100f64fb0]: receiving RTCP SR
2015-07-18 23:24:35.210 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSSimpleQosAnalyzer: lost_percentage=0.000000, int_jitter=5.000000 ms, rt_prop=0.020828 sec
2015-07-18 23:24:35.213 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSSimpleQosAnalyzer: everything is fine.
2015-07-18 23:24:35.218 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSBitrateController: current state is Init
2015-07-18 23:24:35.223 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSQualityIndicator[0x1700da320][audio], remote statistics available:
Loss rate           : 0.0%
Inter-arrival jitter: 0.5ms
RT propagation      : 2.1ms
2015-07-18 23:24:35.229 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:35.958 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] Sending RTCP SR compound message on session [0x1010e1e00].
2015-07-18 23:24:35.965 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio_stream_iterate[0x100f64fb0], local statistics available:
Local current jitter buffer size: 167.4ms
2015-07-18 23:24:35.968 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:37.865 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio stream [0x100f64fb0]: receiving RTCP SR
2015-07-18 23:24:37.870 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:38.877 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] Sending RTCP SR compound message on session [0x1010e1e00].
2015-07-18 23:24:38.885 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio_stream_iterate[0x100f64fb0], local statistics available:
Local current jitter buffer size: 350.0ms
2015-07-18 23:24:38.889 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:41.928 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136453] Sending RTCP SR compound message on session [0x1010e1e00].
2015-07-18 23:24:41.945 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] MSAudio_stream_iterate[0x100f64fb0], local statistics available:
Local current jitter buffer size: 297.8ms
2015-07-18 23:24:41.951 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Linphone core [0x10102ec00] notifying [call_stats_updated]
2015-07-18 23:24:42.528 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Dialog [0x1741a8ea0]: now updated by transaction [0x174143700].
2015-07-18 23:24:42.532 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Changing [client] [BYE] transaction [0x174143700], from state [INIT] to [TRYING]
2015-07-18 23:24:42.536 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] channel [0x102240000]: message sent to [UDP://192.168.31.209:5060], size: [306] bytes
BYE sip:0101101@192.168.31.209:5060 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.31.232:61712;branch=z9hG4bK.nBn0Xvg~W;rport

From: <sip:test2@192.168.31.232>;tag=0zmDcr2

To: <sip:0101101@192.168.31.209>;tag=859743850

CSeq: 112 BYE

Call-ID: 1144529261

Max-Forwards: 70

User-Agent: /mikko1.0 (belle-sip/1.4.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first "200 Ok" you are sending (for the first INVITE you are receiving) contains:

```
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 0
a=inactive
```

This means you are not accepting video when you answer the call. So in this first step, video is still disabled by signalling.

Later, you start video with a re-INVITE, but unfortunatly, the remote device (the intercom) is not replying to this re-INVITE. Instead of receiving a 200 ok, you only receive a provisional 100 Trying. Because this second re-INVITE doesn't complete, video is again, not established by signalling.

The easiest workaround is certainly to answer the first INVITE with video directly. No doubt this should be doable with linphone's API! This may explain why your Android app correctly establish video and why you iOS app doesn't...

Of course, the intercom should answer the second re-INVITE and this would also fix video establishment.

sidenote: your User-Agent string seems not compliant...

```
/mikko1.0 (belle-sip/1.4.1)
```

should be

```
mikko/1.0 (belle-sip/1.4.1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. ~!   How can i answer the first INVITE with video directly.  I use linphone's API . `LinphoneCallParams* paramsCopy = linphone_call_params_copy(linphone_call_get_current_params(call));
                linphone_call_params_enable_video(paramsCopy, TRUE);
                linphone_core_accept_call_update([LinphoneManager getLc], call, paramsCopy);
                linphone_call_params_destroy(paramsCopy);`  Right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with linphone's API and can't confirm, but it seems that linphone_call_params_enable_video may be the required line!

Comment: oh~! I tried. but it seems not work. When the LinphoneCallState change LinphoneCallIncomingReceived -> LinphoneCallEarlyUpdating. I use linphone's answer video API. Always no video. Log message show `linphone_core_update_call() is not allowed in [LinphoneCallEarlyUpdating] state`

Comment: Your log indicate that video wasn't enabled: (2015-07-18 23:24:23.799 LinphoneDemo2[15372:2136209] Don't put video stream on local offer for call [0x101804600]). I found out that the log is coming from linphonecall.c. Obviously, there is some missing element to enable video in the context. Sorry that I can't help here.

Comment: Never mind~.You've helped me a lot.I will also think of other ways to solve.Thank you very much. ~!